# serialization shows only value kind and NOT the value

Tags: c#, serialization

We have data coming from 3rd party system and I have one class designed like this,

```
 public class CollectionProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

and my VS debugger saying value like this which gives me extra details of data type along with result,

[image]
[image]

Now when I serialize this using Newtonsoft,

```
 var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultPacket);
```

it's giving below output with only value kind and NOT the value.

I need string value with double quote, number value withOUT double quote, how to do this?

> [{"Name":"Device ID","Value":{**"ValueKind":3}**}]},{"Name":"CPU0","CollectionProperties":[{"Name":"CPU Load Percentage","Value":{"**ValueKind":4**}}]}]

Comment: **Don't** use an object as a property type. Use the type you expect instead, in this case `int`. What you posted is JSON, not integers. Since you explicitly wrote that you *don't* want that payload parsed, the deserializer returned what the input contained, a JToken

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the only way I found was to use System.Text.Json for serializing :

```cs
string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(resultPacket);
```

The ValueKind property comes when using dynamic objects and expandoObject in my case. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a valid incoming json,

```
[{"Name":"CPU Load Percentage","Value":{"ValueKind":4}}]
```

Change your class to look like this. You can change the class /property name as per your need. Json Attribute is to map your property with incoming JSON property.
Also, you can use `dynamic` or `JObject` if your incoming JSON property can change in future. If it wont, you can use the code below:

```
        public class Value    {
            [JsonProperty("ValueKind")]
            public int ValueKind; 
        }
    
        public class SystemData{
            [JsonProperty("Name")]
            public string Name; 
    
            [JsonProperty("Value")]
            public Value Value; 
        }
    
//Your root class. 
        public class CollectionProperty{
           
            public List<SystemData> SystemDataList; 
        }
```

### Update

Since your json has [{}] that means , its an array or collection of complex objects. {} = class so it seems, there comes a list of class with two properties Name and Value in which again Value is a class or complex object with a property ValueKind of type int.

### Usage

```
CollectionProperty myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollectionProperty>(myJsonResponse);
```

Comment: Thanks, but NOT getting. Could you please explain more, how to design my `CollectionProperty` class

Comment: Root will be replaced by CollectionProperty

Comment: I checked this. it's coming null